# Linux - connect java with HSQLDB

Tags: java, classpath, hsqldb

I want to use hsqldb with a java file. I know that I have to change the classpath somehow.. How can I do it on the terminal?
(The code I have works, tested with an ide)

Comment: Use the `-cp` option...

Comment: When I use the -cp option I get: "Error: Could not find or load main class db"